# How to work with voice over in objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

Its the first time when I work with voice over on objective c. i'm trying to make some simple app for blind community.
tell me necessary classes and methods to work with voice?
what should my application to except play and pause voice?
please show me main protocols and methods with examples.
Full tutorial will be appreciated :-)
video will be perfect

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make the elements in your app accessible in the accessibility tree. By default they are all set to YES, so all the elements are ready by voice over. You don't have to write any code for that.

However you need to write code to post accessibility notifications, and to make some elements not read by voice over.

You can change the voice over settings in the device accessibility settings.

Please read the Apple's Documentation regarding the [UIAccessibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccessibility_Protocol/).